# blocking javascript in chrome is not working

Tags: google-chrome, website, javascript

due to to a problem I want to block Javascript in my browser for
**[*].indiatimes.com**
however when I a add this in chrome://settings/contentExceptions#javascript

snapshot as below[image]

the added block is not being saved when I again open the manage exceptions section of Javascript then this is how it appears
[image]

How do I get rid of this problem? How to save the blocked website in
chrome://settings/contentExceptions#javascript

Comment: The same snapshots as above got repeated except that this time I tried adding *.indiatimes.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct pattern is `[*.]` before `indiatimes.com`. Note that the period, ie `.` is within the square brackets while you've put it outside

[image]

Comment: yes I tried this , this has worked.

Answer (score -1):

Goto setting advanced settings content/privacy content there you can disable/enable whatever you like cookies javascript etc

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.